# Why do polymorphic functions that return polymorphic functions use a gensym in their type?

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

Suppose I have a function `first-value` that takes a value and returns a function that ignores its input and returns the original value:

```
(: first-value (All (A) (-> A (All (B) (-> B A)))))
(define ((first-value a) b)
  a)
```

If I inspect the type of this function in the REPL, I find no surprises:

```
> first-value
- : (All (A) (-> A (All (B) (-> B A))))
#<procedure:first-value>
```

However, if I call the function, the type of the returned function looks a little strange:

```
> (first-value 'foo)
- : (All (g3743) (-> g3743 'foo))
#<procedure>
```

The `B` type variable was replaced with a gensym. Is there any particular reason this happens? I'm using Racket 6.1.1

Comment: I've submitted [a bug report](https://github.com/racket/typed-racket/issues/37) for this because I think it's poor behavior. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

In a formal grammar symbols may be replaced by other symbols. If an ostensive terminal symbol is replaced by another terminal as in `B` replace by `g3743` this is equivalent to renaming.

Because there is no way to determine what `B` will be during macro-expansion of `(define ((first-value...` the `gensym` avoids future ambiguity or collisions [remember `define` is a special form/macro].

Keep in mind that the macro expansion can happen inside another macro expansion, and the `gensym` allows the `B` in `(first-value 'foo)` to be a different type than the `B` in `(first-value 'bar)` during the 'outer' expansion in something like:

```
 (myMacro (first-value 'foo)
          (first-value 'bar))
```

Comment: Why doesn't this affect the function before it's applied, and why doesn't it affect functions that return polymorphic functions but are not themselves polymorphic? For example, `(: first-value (-> Symbol (All (B) (-> B Symbol))))` doesn't have this renaming occur. This seems to *only* happen for polymorphic functions that return polymorphic functions, and *only* for the returned function. It strikes me as very odd.